# Get Datatable From csv file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, csv, oledb

I'm using oledb connection and query to retrieve datafrom .xls and .xlsx file to Datatable it works well here's code

Connection String

```
MyConnection1= New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 ;Data Source=" & spath1 & " ;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'")
```

Query Code

```
Dim connection As OleDbConnection = MyConnection1
Dim query As String = "select * from [" & Sheet1name & "]"
Dim dA As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, MyConnection1)
Dim dsA As New DataSet
dA.Fill(dsA)
Dim tablFille AS Datatable = dsA.Tables(0)
```

But i don't know how to do same with .csv files. . . . .

Comment: Did you try the same with csv file? What happens?

Comment: Connection String I don't know how to

Comment: Am not sure but that may work, try with same connection string.

Comment: Have you tried just opening the file directly and parsing by looking for a comma?

Comment: CSV files are **text** files. Open the csv for input and read it **line by line** (depending on your file size you could decide to open the entire file **at once** and then split it into lines - you can do this with files as small as about 100MB). Split it on the separator (if it's produced by Excel, then the separator is a semicolon (**;**)) and build your INSERT statements to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
string file = "(Write your file name here)";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection
       ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + 
         Path.GetDirectoryName(file ) + 
         "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");

conn.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter 
           ("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(file), conn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet("TempDS");
adapter.Fill(ds);

conn.Close();
```

Comment: It shows some cells empty . . .In file it contains data but it shows bull here

Comment: Check this link - http://carllbrown.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/populate-dataset-from-csv-delimited_18.html

Comment: Refer this also -
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/952ab4ca-97d4-4cc8-9db8-d5d562161461/populate-dataset-from-csv?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Answer (score 0):

I found the use of the FileHelpers engine an easy and fast way.
http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

You simply define your file, this one is of an imaginary customer.csv

```
<DelimitedRecord(",")> _
Public Class Customer

    Public CustId As Integer

    Public Name As String

    Public Balance As Decimal

    <FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy")> _
    Public AddedDate As DateTime

End Class
```

And you can use the engine

```
Dim engine As New FileHelperEngine(GetType( Customer))

' To Read Use:
Dim res As  Customer() = DirectCast(engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt"), Customer())



For Each cust As Customer In res)


Console.WriteLine("Customer Info:")
Console.WriteLine(cust.Name + " - " + _
                  cust.AddedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy"))
Next
```